# Connect to Postgres DB in AWS using IAM Authentication with SSL

Tags: c#, postgresql, amazon-rds, npgsql

I have an RDS instance running Postgres which has IAM Authentication enabled. I can successfully connect using an IAM token via powershell, but I'm having trouble with certificates when trying to connect using the `Npgsql` library with C# (targeting .Net Core 3.1) from Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.8.5 (on .Net Framework 4.8).

Note, I've been referencing this AWS page, which gives download links for the certificates.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html

I've also been referencing this page to guide me through getting this set up.
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-postgresql-connect-using-iam/

---

I can connect with PowerShell, using:

```
$ENV:RDSHOST="my-postgres-instance.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com"
$ENV:PGPASSWORD="$(aws rds generate-db-auth-token --hostname $ENV:RDSHOST --port 5432 --region eu-west-1 --username my_db_user)"
psql -h $ENV:RDSHOST -p 5432 "sslmode=verify-full sslrootcert=rds-ca-2019-root.pem dbname=my_db user=my_db_user password=$ENV:PGPASSWORD"
```

However when I try to open a connection with C# using the `Npgsql` library with the code below, I get an exception:

```
var host = "my-postgres-instance.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com";
var port = 5432;
var user = "my_db_user";

var token = RDSAuthTokenGenerator.GenerateAuthToken(RegionEndpoint.EUWest1, host, port, user);

var builder = new NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder
{
    Host = host,
    Port = port,
    Database = "my_db",
    Username = user,
    Password = token,
    SslMode = SslMode.Require,
    RootCertificate = @"C:\Path\To\Cert\rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem",
};

using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
}
```

> Npgsql.NpgsqlException: 'Exception while performing SSL handshake
>
> AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

It's worth noting that I *can* connect setting  `TrustServerCertificate = true`, however as I understand it, this is masking the problem and reducing security, and is not advisable.

The AWS page linked above mentions:

> If your application is on Microsoft Windows and requires a PKCS7 file, you can download the PKCS7 certificate bundle. This bundle contains both the intermediate and root certificates at https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.p7b.

I've tried specifying this `p7b` file as the `NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder.ClientCertificate`, but this causes a different exception when opening the connection:

> Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper.WindowsCryptographicException: 'Cannot find the original signer.'

---

Anyone able to help me understand how to connect? It's worth noting that I'm not very familiar with detting up SSL connections or dealing with certificates, so bear that in mind.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything since it is working in power shell except make sure the Net version is capable of doing the encryption mode.  for older version of et you need to add at beginning of code the static parameter : ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;  the certificate need to be loaded into your user and machine certificate stores.  You do not need to do in code every time.  TLS is automatically initiated when your URL has HTTPS.  the server sends a certificate block with names of certificate and then client looks up certificate in stores.

Comment: If you have Net 4.7.2 or later it is recommended that you set the Config file to use TLS from operating system rather than do it inside Net.  Especially if the version of TLS is 1.3.

Comment: @jdweng Yeah I'm struggling to understand how I can connect from powershell using the `psql` cmd client but cannot connect with the `Npgsql` library, leading me to think that perhaps it's an issue with the library (I dont like to jump to conclusions though). I've tried specifying `SecurityProtocolType` as you suggests but get the same error. Worth noting that I'm on .Net Core 3.1.

Comment: What version of Net/VS?  It looks like the version of Net isn't working with the encryption mode but the operating system does work.  So you need a version of Net that will allow you to use the operating system.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls

Comment: I'm using VS 2019 version 16.8.5 (on .Net Framework 4.8), and I'm targeting .Net Core 3.1.

Comment: There are four issues 1)  Using Net 4.7 or later so you can use operating system for TLS so youi can use any encryption mode 2) Using Net 4.7.2 or later so Net can properly Target Core 3) Making sure operating system supports encryption mode.  Windows updates will usually solve these issues.  With Mobile devices you need to update Kernel to a version that support encryption mode 4) Make sure your client isn't specifying TLS 1.0 or 1.1.  New version of windows should automatically do this.